# Get twodimensional array positions out of integer

Tags: java, math, multidimensional-array, processing, pixel

I am loading pixels out of an image.
for every pixel I check the color and create an image, I now want to add this image inside of an two dimensional array.

```
int MAPWIDTH = 64; // in pixels
int MAPHEIGHT = 16; // in pixel
PImage[][] forGroundMap;

PImage file = loadImage(path);


file.loadPixels();
   
   int size = file.width * file.height;
   
   for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {

    int y = divideBy(i, MAPWIDTH);

    //forGroundMap[y][x] == something what is x and y here
   }
```

For reference: The images are always 64 in height and 32 in width.

To get the position I have tried to divide the current iteration by the width to know what row I am currently at.

```
int divideBy(int number, int timesIn) {
int count = 0;

while (number >= timesIn) {
    number = number - timesIn;
    count++;
    println(number);
}

return count;
```

}

This however doesn't give me back the column inside my row And I am not sure if this will work at all and how to continue forward.

Comment: `PImage image` is not being used at all.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking, but what is the value of `MAPWIDTH`,

Comment: Asume you have a big table with rows and collumns but you only know the number of the row * collumn you are on. I need to know which row and collumn I am on.

Comment: Well get rid of the stuff that isn't part of the problem, because based upon what you have coded and what you have posted, it is impossible to guess what you are asking.  Not trying to be mean, but can not help in its current format.

Comment: I edited my code, I need to know the row and column of the 2d array since I only have an number of what the pixel position is. I go through every pixel in an image and I want to set every pixel inside of an 2d array

Comment: so if the pixel number is less that 64 (MAPWIDTH) you are on row 1 ? 65 - 128 = rows 2?  This is simple division isnt it?  Am I still not understanding you?

Comment: Yes this is correct, I think. but I am not sure how to program this while also getting the column. which is the remainder when you dont have enough for 64 anymore. I tried to do it with the divideBy method. But I am stuck here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you appears to be wanting is simple division math.

```
int y = 1 / 64;
System.out.println (y);
y = 65 / 64;
System.out.println (y);
```

**edit**

To get the x value as well use modulo

```
int x = 1 / 64;
int y = 1 % 64;
System.out.printf ("you are at [%d,%d]%n", x,y);
x = 65 / 64;
y = 65 % 64;
System.out.printf ("you are at [%d,%d]%n", x,y);
```

Comment: This doesnt fix my problem of the x axis. I think my divideBy method already does the y correctly. I need the x variable. If my method works as expected. And yes it should be simple division I just really dont know what the math here is.

Comment: see my edit, no looping in divideBy should be required